# Objetos do Banco como parâmetros de Stored Procedure

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Por que quando passamos objetos do banco como parâmetros em uma stored procedure eles não são aceitos?

Ex:

```
@COLUNA nvarchar(30),
@VARIAVEL nvarchar(50)
SELECT * FROM TBL_TESTE WHERE @COLUNA = @VARIAVEL
```

A unica alternativa seriam consultas dinâmicas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O SQL Server Não concatena comandos apenas valores, então você pode passar valores para que um comando seja montando e executado, Exemplo:

```
@COLUNA nvarchar(30),
 @VARIAVEL nvarchar(50)

declare @CMD varchar(4000)

set @CMD = 'SELECT * FROM TBL_TESTE WHERE '+@COLUNA+' = '+@VARIAVEL+''
 exec sp_executeSQL @CMD
```

Se ainda tiver duvidas avisa

Answer (score -2):

```
declare
    @campo varchar(50),
    @valor varchar(50),
    @qry   varchar(max)

set @campo = 'Inscricao';
set @valor = '123456';
set @qry = 'select * from tabela where ' + @inscricao + ' = ' + @valor;

Exec (@qry)
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que esse código faz?

Comment: Olá Marcela, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Aqui no site os usuários geralmente prezam por respostas objetivas e que expliquem o que está sendo feito. Por exemplo, você apenas forneceu um código, mas respondeu exatamente ao que foi perguntado. Provavelmente essas foram as razões dos negativos que a resposta recebeu. Seria interessante se você pudesse editar a sua resposta para adicionar alguns comentários acima. Abraço!